# Get full URL image with object ID - Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I write a Serializer in Django Rest Framework about Profile have `Avatar Image` but I want to get full URL Image instead of ID.

My Serializers (which return `profile_pic_url` is ID):

```
class ProfileDetailSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    profile_pic_url = SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = [
            'profile_pic_url',
        ]

    def get_profile_pic_url(self, obj):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        profile_pic_url = obj.profile_pic_url.image
        return request.build_absolute_uri(profile_pic_url)
```

This code returns this issues:

`'ImageFieldFile' object has no attribute 'find'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need provide to `build_absolute_uri` picture url but not ImageField itself:

```
return request.build_absolute_uri(profile_pic_url.url)
```